# How to find houses on types of land with less risk of damage from earthquakes?

Tags: earthquake

If the general geographic location, i.e. city or metro area is fixed, what methods and data sources should I use to know what land areas in the region have less risk of damage to houses from earthquakes? Someone told me to avoid hilly areas but I thought that is too simplistic. Flat ground may have comparable risk of damages. How can I learn more about this?

Comment: have you called the city hall?

Answer (score 1):

If you're in a first world country, talk to your local planning commission.  They should have huge amounts of data about seismic stability down to a block-by-block resolution.  They will have information in a detail that is far beyond your current understanding of the field, so be prepared to learn a lot!

They can tell you block by block, even property by property, where the risks are, where they are not, and how to build for best survivability.  That last bit will be mandatory, actually.

Having licked the earthquake problem, you *really* ought to think about the far more dangerous factors in earthquake country: the brothers **Wildfire** and **Mudslides**.

Comment: How to contact such a planning commission for the Portland metro area for example? Is there a website to search relevant info by oneself?

Comment: The standard way: go to City Hall and go around asking people.  The good stuff isn't online, and probably never will be, as the small number of bona-fide stakeholders don't need it to be.